# Load js view with jQuery using Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm studying Rails, and start with Rails 4, but using a Rails 3 book.

**Book:** Beginning Rails 3 - Cloves Carneiro Jr.,andRida Al Barazi

In certain chapter **Responding to Requests with :format => :js**

### app/views/articles/show.html.erb

```
<%= render @article %>

<hr>

<h3>Comments</h3>
<div id="comments">
  <%= render @article.comments %>
</div>

<% # render :file => 'comments/new' %>
<%= link_to 'new comment', new_article_comment_path(@article, :format => :js), :remote => true, :id => 'new_comment_link' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

But this code:

```
<%= link_to 'new comment', new_article_comment_path(@article, :format => :js), :remote => true, :id => 'new_comment_link' %>
```

Doesn't work.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6lQ86cS.png]

```
  Rendered comments/new.js.erb (2051.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2065ms

ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:245


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (17.0ms)
```

I create a `new.js.erb` in `app/views/comments/new.js.erb`:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'comments/new') %>").insertAfter('#comments');
$("#new_comment_link").hide();
```

But in Google Chrome console the request return **HTTP 500**.

### rake routes:

https://gist.github.com/6904410

### routes

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "articles#index"

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :users

  resource :session
  match '/login' => "sessions#new", :as => "login", :via => 'get'
  match '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", :as => 'logout', :via => 'get'

end
```

### model/article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :body, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :comments

  # Check later
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories

  scope :published, lambda {where("articles.published_at IS NOT NULL")}
  scope :draft, lambda {where("articles.published_at IS NULL")}
  scope :recent, lambda { published.where("articles.published_at > ?", 1.week.ago.to_date) }
  scope :where_title, lambda { |term| where("articles.title LIKE ?", "%#{term}%}") }

  def long_title
    "#{title} - #{published_at}"
  end

  def published?
    published_at.present?
  end

  def owned_by?(owner)
    return false unless owner.is_a? User
    user == owner
  end

end
```

### model/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :article

  validates :name, :email, :body, :presence => true
  validate :article_should_be_published

  after_create :email_article_author

  def article_should_be_published
    errors.add(:article_id, "is not published yet") if article && !article.published?
  end

  def email_article_author
    logger.info("We will notify #{article.user.email} in Chapter 9")
  end

end
```

### Partially Solved

I change the path to render file, for: `comments/new.html.erb`, and works.

But, I don't know if is the best/correct soluction. For example: in render action, don't have any `:format` attribute.

---

### Environment

- Sublime Text 2
- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Rails 4.0.0
- Ruby 2.0.0
- jQuery 1.10

---

## Thanks

Comment: What does CommentsController#new do? Just renders comments/new.js.erb? Did you check the logs, as the error message suggests?

Comment: Just render the comment form. Nothing more. (Is just a book example)

Comment: @Teoulas I update my question. Now you can analyse the error (because I not understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I don't if is the better solution, but works:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'comments/new', :formats => :html) %>").insertAfter('#comments');
$("#new_comment").hide().slideDown();
$("#new_comment_link").hide();
```

### Solution

```
:formats => :html
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that with your

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'comments/new') %>").insertAfter('#comments');
```

what happend here is that you created an infinite loop (yeeeahaa!)
because the

```
file: 'comments/new'
```

will render comments/new.js.erb. but this will call it self.

try test it with:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'form') %>").insertAfter('#comments');
```

and it should work.